AVRO - nullable logicalType decimal payload error
I'm trying to send messages to a topic using confluent's lib-kstreams, but I'm having some problems.
My avro is defined as:
"type": [
    "null",
    { 
      "type":"bytes",
      "logicalType":"decimal", 
      "precision":2, 
      "scale": 0 
    }
]

As you can see, this field is optional, so I have to prepare the payload like this.
"value":{"decimal":"@1ó33333"}
But I get this error,
:icdmnegord-k6-engine-54f4cb846b-5gnr7:    GoError: Failed to encode data, OriginalError: cannot decode textual record "com.package.v1.Envelope": cannot decode textual union: cannot decode textual record "com.package.v1.Record": cannot determine codec: "decimal" for key: "value" for key: "costs" ....
I've tried these approaches:
"value":{"decimal":"@1ó33333"},
"value":{"bytes":"@1ó33333"},
